# Что за модуль bluebird?

Tags: javascript, promise

`bluebird`, как я понял, это библиотека промисов.
Но зачем она нужна, если в ES6 и так поддерживает промисы?
Или `bluebird` — это те же самые промисы что в нативном ES6, только с дополнительными улучшениями?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34960886/2076787

Comment: @D-side Еще есть модуль fs require('fs'); Можно про него пару слов. Это тоже библиотека промисов как и bluebird?

Comment: Откуда такой вывод?

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS, Почти. Только полностью неверно.

Comment: @Other Можно про него пару слов? чтобы тему не создавать.

Comment: Это модель NodeJS, который обеспечивает работу с файловой системой. В JS нет этих интерфейсов, поэтому это чисто нодовский модуль. Хотя асинхронные операции там есть и уже их можно в промис обернуть, хотя и не нужно, ибо есть синхронные аналоги.

Comment: Bluebird был написан когда нативных промисов ещё не было, а спецификация уже была. И они до сих пор местами быстрее нативных промисов

Comment: Ну и http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-bluebird.html